# Ejecución a medias de php artisan queue:work (Killed)

Tags: php, laravel, azure

Estoy tratando de ejecutar el comando de **php artisan queue:work** en producción pero el sistema operativo me mata el proceso. Estoy usando la tabla job para guardas los jobs. `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`.

[image: Captura del problema que tengo]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, simplemente hice esto php artisan queue:work --memory=512 --timeout=6000. aca en el timeout trate de ponerle un valor alto para que no se pare el proceso.